# sharing settings between multiple apps

Tags: android, settings, data-sharing

I am new to android development and i am looking for the best possible solution to my problem.

I am open for nearly everything. I am currently in "experimental phase" so i can turn the design upside-down if needed.

I am working on a series of apps (in the end about 5-10) which should be able to share global settings.

The apps will all communicating with a WebService and have to identify itself to use its functions.
The identification includes a "device id". Every app should send the same ID while on the same device.
I want to create the ID on the first start of one of the apps and then use it from any of those apps.

I searched a long time but didn't find a solution.
In most of the questions i found here that are related to my problem the use of a ContentProvider is recommended.
I think that is not possible in my situation since i do not have a central app that can provide the settings.

Here are some questions i already read through:

[Android sharing data (state,value,config) between multiple apps & activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055145/android-sharing-data-state-value-config-between-multiple-apps-activities)

[I am unable to get Shared Preferences of other application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086210/i-am-unable-to-get-shared-preferences-of-other-application)

[Copy/share configurations between paid/free versions of Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070689/copy-share-configurations-between-paid-free-versions-of-android-app)

[Android Shared Internal Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241282/android-shared-internal-storage)

[Create and Share a File from Internal Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170386/create-and-share-a-file-from-internal-storage)

[Saving public files in the internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764562/android-saving-public-files-in-the-internal-storage)

Since MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE are deprecated the following is also not what i am looking for but very close: [Sharing files/ installation directory between two apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530972/sharing-files-installation-directiory-between-two-apps)

I've also read about ANDROID_ID but this seems not to be a good choice.

I was hoping one of you can lead me to a good solution.

Comment: Why are these separate apps? Why is this not one single app?

Comment: This is because every app serves another purpose. You can think of modules if you like. For example App1 is for tracking construction machines, App2 is for rapporting worked hours on different building lots, App3 is for searching a product catalog, and so on. The apps do not depend on each other.

Comment: "share global settings" implies that they "depend on each other".

Comment: I am sorry not beeing clear enough. I try to clarify: Apart from the "device id" setting i try to share, they do not depend on each other.